# jasmine Expected spy myLinks to have been called error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am having a hard time understanding jasmine spyOn function.
I wrote a simple function and test if my method was called:

```
function myView() {
  myLinks();
}
```

Here are my tests:

```
describe('#myView', function() {
    it('updates link', function() {
      var spyEvent = spyOn(window, 'myLinks');
      expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

This returns the following failure:

```
Expected spy myLinks to have been called
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the `myView()` function so the `myLinks()` have been called.

```
function myLinks(){
    //some tasks
}    

function myView() {
  myLinks();
}
```

This two function above are declared in **window** object, then you create a spy object pointing to the window.

```
describe('#myView', function() {
    myView();//Call the method so the myLinks was called too
    it('updates link', function() {
      var spyEvent = spyOn(window, 'myLinks');
      expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```